# Emtrac Plus Battery

Tags: battery

Can someone tell me where is Emtrac Plus Silver Alloy Batteries manufactured. The brand was offered to me recently, looked very good and I bought it. Hope it performs as well as it looks.

Comment: I believe the are manufactured in India. Wouldn't trust it myself as they aren't available anywhere locally and I don't know much about them, but that doesn't mean they're bad.

Answer (score 4):

The batteries are manufactured in India. The company which produces them is called [Mindtrac](http://www.mindtrac.com/profile.html). The reason you don't know much about them is they received seed capital in 2000 from JPMorgan as a startup. They produce tires, batteries, and some other stuff. They are supposed to be [ISO 14001 certified](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_14001_-_key_benefits.pdf), so apparently they worry about the environment, which is a good thing, especially for a Lead-Acid Battery manufacturer. I'm sure it would be pretty hard for them to get, considering.

Comment: ISO is only for registering, not certifying. So a company can be ISO registered, but not ISO certified. ISO varies greatly from one country to another, so ISO 14001 in India will not mean the same thing that ISO 14001 means in the U.S. Silly, since it is supposed to be a 'standards body', but this is how it actually works in practice. I know this from working for many years with a Chinese factory.

Comment: @Paul - I can only imagine! Thanks for the add :o) BTW, they label themselves as [ISO 14001 certified](http://www.mindtrac.com/gsi.html). Just going off what they've stated.

Comment: That may be what Mindtrac states on their webpage, but companies get this wrong all of the time. There is an ISO page explaining this, as well as the fact that it is a violation of the ISO IP to use the ISO trademark without the permission of the ISO (i.e., you can't put it on your products, brochures, website, etc.), but companies still violate even that all of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that ​Amaron and Emtrac plus ​are manufactured in same factory in India. Both same quality. Heard, quality is very good. I bought Emtrac Plus battery only 6 months ago. Lets hope all goes well. My friend used Amaron battery and it lasted over 4 years.

Comment: Now, I am not particularly concerned about which factory manufactures Emtrac Plus Batteries in India. It is a very reliable battery. I would strongly recommend Emtrac Plus. If you own a SUV, you will need a heavy duty  battery like Emtrac Plus.